# How to disable access to certain static files from /resources/META-INF/resources in production using Quarkus?

Tags: jakarta-ee, development-environment, quarkus, static-content, meta-inf

Im having a small html page in my **META-INF/resources** to test certain things in my development environment with **gradle quarkusDev**.

**ContainerRequestFilters** don´t get called when static content is being requested, so no way to prevent it there, and I do not want to exclude those files when building my docker container.

Is there a way to disable the access to certain files in **production**?